# How can I fix this error that pops up when installing pystan via pip install?

Tags: python, pip, stan, pystan

This is what I typed into my Windows Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\jeane\Desktop\ethan\stan> pip install pystan
```

This was my output:

```
Collecting pystan
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/a1/fdf8906311733b7894aad1395d4d43afbbc79ca7573a07200eb105c5938c/pystan-2.18.0.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jeane\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wwq65uzi\pystan\setup.py", line 122, in <module>
    from Cython.Build.Inline import _get_build_extension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\jeane\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wwq65uzi\pystan\
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can try installing Anaconda.Search google for "Anaconda",download it and install it.After that,search "Anaconda Prompt" in your Windows system and install pystan with this command:

```
conda install pystan -c conda-forge
```

After that,you should see this:

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\User\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pystan


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pystan-2.17.1.0            |   py37h830ac7b_2        14.3 MB  conda-forge
    openssl-1.0.2p             |       hfa6e2cd_0         5.4 MB  conda-forge
    conda-4.5.11               |        py37_1000         654 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        20.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pystan:  2.17.1.0-py37h830ac7b_2 conda-forge

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:   4.5.11-py37_0                       --> 4.5.11-py37_1000  conda-forge
    openssl: 1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0                   --> 1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0 conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Simply press y.Anaconda will automatically download and install it.

Comment: Not sure why...maybe because of some unknow error.How can I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install what it says there?

```
pip install Cython
```

should work

Comment: Ahh, I just installed Cython, but this message pops up now:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\jeane\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3x4tsts4\pystan\setup.py", line 124, in <module>
        logger.warning("MSVC is not supported")
    NameError: name 'logger' is not defined` I installed logger afterward, but it was the same output.

Comment: this are the instructions you need, in short, you need to install MingW-w64